# Error while executing a.out from C shell

Tags: shell, executable

I am in my home directory. And there is an executable `a.out` in there. I want to execute it like-

```
/bin/csh ~/a.out
^F^E@@@@@▒^A▒^A^H^C^D^B^B@^B@^\^\^A^A^E@@: Event not found.
```

Its not that I cannot simply run

```
./a.out
```

that works perfectly fine. But I want to know why it is not working the other way round?

Also,

```
/bin/csh tmp/script
```

works fine where `script` is a normal text file containing some shell commands like `echo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/bin/csh filename` tells the shell to read shell commands from `filename`. If you want the shell to execute the file (which is *not* the same thing), you should use `/bin/csh -c ./a.out`.